# R- Calculate mean of Time variable mean(DateTime)

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

This is an example of my dataset:

```
> head(daily[,c(6,7)])->test
> head(test)
                timeMin  min
316 2013-05-02 13:45:00 3239
317 2013-05-03 12:30:00 3260
318 2013-05-04 12:30:00 3165
319 2013-05-05 12:30:00 3404
320 2013-05-06 12:30:00 3514
321 2013-05-07 13:15:00 3626
```

I need mean(timeMin), in order to know what´s the time of the day (hour:minute) at what the event usually happens. I have tried this:

```
library(lubridate)
> test$hourMin<-paste(hour(test$timeMin),minute(test$timeMin),sep=":”)
> test$hourMin <- hm(test$hourMin)
```

And I got this:

```
> head(test)
                timeMin  min    hourMin
316 2013-05-02 13:45:00 3239 13H 45M 0S
317 2013-05-03 12:30:00 3260 12H 30M 0S
318 2013-05-04 12:30:00 3165 12H 30M 0S
319 2013-05-05 12:30:00 3404 12H 30M 0S
320 2013-05-06 12:30:00 3514 12H 30M 0S
321 2013-05-07 13:15:00 3626 13H 15M 0S
```

however, when I try to calculate the mean I had no result:

```
> mean(test$hourMin)
[1] 0
```

It should be straightforward, but I don´t know how to do it, since I am a beginner. I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: What gives `class(timeMin)` ?

Comment: > class(test$timeMin)
[1] "POSIXct" “POSIXt"  > class(test$hourMin)
[1] "Period"
attr(,"package")
[1] "lubridate"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really not elegant, but the only way I found for now is to change the date components to the same day and to compute the mean on the result. With `lubridate` :

```
time <- df$timeMin
time <- update(time, year=2000, month=1, mday=1)
mean(time)
# [1] "2000-01-01 12:50:00 CET"
```

Hopefully someone will provide something better...

Comment: Your solution seems to work for my entire dataset
`> mean(daily$hourMin,na.rm=TRUE)
[1] "2000-01-01 14:30:45 UTC"`
However, when I ask for the mean by "treatment" using tapply it gives me an unformatted result I don't know how to deal with
`> tapply(daily$hourMin,daily$treatment, FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
  ambient  elevated 
946736754 946737321`

Comment: Please, how could I know the mean subsetting by treatment?

Answer (score 0):

I'm calculating seconds past 1st Jan, 2013 midnight and then taking mean of that and adding it back to 1st Jan, 2013 midnight.

I guess there are packages that can do this from just one command but if you, like me, don't wish to rely too much on packages then this solution should work for you.

```
library(data.table)

timetable <- data.table(TimeMin = c("2013-05-02 13:45:00",
                                    "2013-05-03 12:30:00",
                                    "2013-05-04 12:30:00",
                                    "2013-05-05 12:30:00",
                                    "2013-05-06 12:30:00",
                                    "2013-05-07 13:15:00")
)

timetable <- timetable[, TimePastMin := 
                           difftime(
                               "2013-01-01 00:00:00",
                               TimeMin,
                               units = "secs"
                           )
                       ]

meanTimePastMin <- mean(timetable[, TimePastMin])

meanTimeMin <- strptime("2013-01-01 00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") - meanTimePastMin

meanTimeMin
# "2013-05-05 00:50:00 IST"
```

Comment: Your solution is very clever. However, the result doesn't look very logic to me, since the values range between 12:30 and 13:45, and therefore the mean should be in between. Your result is 00:50, so probably is in a wrong format and it really means 12:50. Am I right?

Comment: In addition, when I try to get the mean grouped by the variable "treatment" (i.e. ambient and elevated concentration), the result is unformatted and I cannot read it
`> tapply(daily$meanTimeMin,daily$treatment, FUN=mean)  
   ambient   elevated   
1372714379 1372714379`

Comment: I haven't checked the answer but it looks correct. The avg of 1,3,5,7 is 4 and not an odd number, for instance. If you take the mean of just the HHMI component and remove the ddmmyy component then you should get something around 1300 and not 0100 though. Your grouped mean might be the number of seconds after R's zeroth data (1st Jan 1970, please recheck) so your average in this case can be calculated as `meanTimeMin <- strptime("1970-01-01 00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") +  1372714379`